# Search - autocomplete - hover a result to features in dropdown

Tags: navigation, search-results, hover, autocomplete, task-flow

I am working on a project where a user has to navigate to any feature for any product. So I came up with a search box component. Here the user can search for a product and when a user hovers on a result it shows features where he can go to.

[image]
Is this the ideal solution? If not can you suggest me an ideal flow for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Debatable. From my experience, I usually avoid dropdowns and especially displaying important information on them. In your situation, you are *assuming* that the user will hover over the product and wait for something to be displayed.

Unfortunately this is just not the mental model of a search-and-suggestion pattern. This should only be used to show the user what items are available. One website with impeccable UX that nailed this functionality is https://www.bhphotovideo.com/ . The search feature is used to show you what they have and you might be looking for. Everything else comes after you reach the product page:

[image]